# how the python slicing inserting new elements in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am working on Python slicing, and I got confussed when the elemnts showed up in a undesired pattern

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,78,]
a[2:1] = [7,9]
```

I tried to enter 7,9 into a existing list, I am getting below output

```
[1, 2, 7, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 78]
```

My point is with the positive slicing, if we are trying to access the elements in a reverse manner, it gives empty list.

- So, how even this is adding elements to the list?
- Even if its adding then how come 9 is placed after 7 in the list?

I hope my question makes sense.

Please suggest.
Thank you.